# MATLAB deployment: How can i make my .exe file can be use by other computer?

Tags: user-interface, version-control, matlab, matlab-deployment

I've created a deployment project which works rather well and now I want to add it to source control repository for others to use.

The main problem I'm facing is that the `.prj` file which `deploytool` creates contains absolute paths which will not work on other computers. I have already installed MCR and I can create the `.exe` file but it can be used on my computer only. How can I make the project can be used with other computer also??

Comment: yes, deploytool gives sometimes unexpected behaviours...try to read this discussion_ http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297681,I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should be able to package your executable for distribution. You then need to have all users have the path to the proper MCR libraries and to your executable and they should be able to use it.

We do this in my company and here is how it works:

1. the matlab code is compiled to a .exe
2. the .exe is copied to a network drive to which everyone has read access rights
3. frequent users have their own local version of the MCR for faster startup time and execution
4. the MCR is also installed on the network for access. Non-frequent users have the proper path to this network location in their path

We've been using this for the past 3 years without problem. The executables are compiled on a separate machine and simply moved to the network share as is. No path problems.

Hope this helps